# trouble linking lapack

Tags: linux, linker, lapack, gfortran

i am trying to link lapack and a simple

```
locate lapack
```

returns

```
/usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3
/usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3.2.1
```

so in am trying to link it with

```
gfortran -o linreg driver.f90 LFsubroutines.f90 -L/usr/lib64 -llapack -fimplicit-none
```

but i get the following error:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
```

what is the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have the `liblapack.so` or `liblapack.a` file there (maybe you didn't install dev(el) package). You may try specifying the complete path instead

```
gfortran -o linreg driver.f90 LFsubroutines.f90 /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3 -fimplicit-none
```

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the following packages if you don't have the devel packages installed already on your system.

```
sudo yum install libgfortran libf2c blas lapack
```

Give that a shot...