# Trouble linking llapacke

Tags: c, macos, makefile, lapack, lapacke

I'm learning to use [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) and [LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) on C, and I'm having trouble with the very first step: importing and linking the libraries.

My device is a Mac, and apparently neither Xcode nor the compiler can find *cblas.h*, *lapack.h*, or *lapacke.h*, while all three are definitely is there in */usr/local/opt/openblas/include*.
I ended up writing the full path in the header like:

```
#include </usr/local/opt/openblas/include/cblas.h>
#include </usr/local/opt/openblas/include/lapacke.h>
```

With this (ugly) solution, Xcode and the compiler can now find the functions, but there's issue in linking `-llapacke` while making the executable.

There isn't any problem in linking `-lapack` and `-lblas`, but when I try `-llapacke`, I get the following error

```
ld: library not found for -llapacke
```

I checked, all three .h files are in */usr/local/opt/openblas/include/*.

How can I solve this issue?

**What I've tried so far:**

I reinstalled (using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager))) libraries *cblas* and *lapack*, but it didn't fix it.

I also tried linking the library with the full path by doing this (following an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016815/how-to-include-needed-c-library-using-gcc)):

```
gcc -o main main.o utils.o -lm -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib -llapacke -llapack -lblas
```

I also tried adding to the search path following an answer on [this page](https://github.com/owlbarn/owl/issues/389), and it didn't work:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig
```

++ My OS is [macOS v10.15.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina), and my Xcode is 12.4.

++++ I also checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370189/trouble-linking-lapack) with a very similar title, and it's not helpful (the question is quite different, and just the title is similar).

Comment: When you say "I also tried adding to the search path" about the link to the github issue, what do you mean exactly? Because it says you should `export` it. It's an environment variable for `pkg-config`. You can use `pkg-config` in the `gcc` command line. Not sure if this is the same on a mac, but on linux like: `gcc myfile.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs openblas)`

Comment: @EmanuelP What I did was exactly running this command:

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig

(Is that what you mean?)

And it doesn't fix the issue. I still get the same error